# Python: Is there a way to have a setup of env. before calling a function and after that restore the previous env.?

Tags: python

My scenario:

I have a variable holding a link. e.g. `REMOTE_API = "http://<site>/api/a/b/c"`
This link stays the same all the time so it can be thought of as a constant.
It is used in many parts of the program.
But there are few parts of the program where the link needs to be changed e.g. `REMOTE_API =  "http://<site>/api/<user_name>/a/b/c"` only if some condition is met. This condition is dictated by a config. file that may change without notice.

Is there a way to change the variable default before running a function and at the end of the function to switch back?

e.g.

```
@prepare_env(<if condition is met>)
def func():
  <...>
  call_api(REMOTE_API) #  "http://<site>/api/<user_name>/a/b/c"
  <...>

if __name__ == "__main__":
  call_api_with_default(REMOTE_API) #  REMOTE_API = "http://<site>/api/a/b/c"
  func() # codition is met REMOTE_API =  "http://<site>/api/<user_name>/a/b/c"
  an_other_call_with_default(REMOTE_API) #  REMOTE_API = "http://<site>/api/a/b/c"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write a function which takes a function and calls it, setting and restoring the environment variable as needed. E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# content of env.py
import os

def call_with_env_var(f, var_name, var_value):
  old_value = os.environ[var_name]
  os.environ[var_name] = var_value
  ret = f()
  os.environ[var_name] = old_value

def print_var(name):
  print(f'value of {name}: {os.environ[name]}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print_var('HOME')
  call_with_env_var(
    lambda: print_var('HOME'),
    'HOME',
    'xyz'
  )
  print_var('HOME')
```

```
$ ./env.py                                
value of HOME: /home/etuardu
value of HOME: xyz
value of HOME: /home/etuardu
$ echo $HOME                              
/home/etuardu
```